# could not broadcast input array from shape

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a video from .mp4 file.

I'm geting error :
  File "demoprotoupsilon.py", line 271, in Display
    PlayVideo(age)
  File "demoprotoupsilon.py", line 217, in PlayVideo
    bg[y1:y2, x1:x2] = frame
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (360,480,3) into shape (360,480,4)

the source code :

```
    def PlayVideo(age):
   print("toto");
   birthyear = datetime.datetime.now().year - age
   videoFilePath = f"media/video/decades/{int(round(birthyear, -1))}.mp4"
   print(videoFilePath)
   vid = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFilePath)
   bg = GetDisplayImgContent()
   if vid.isOpened():
      print("in vidopen")
      while vid.isOpened():
         print("in while")
         ret, frame = vid.read()
         if ret:
            print("img OK")
            #frame = cv2.bitwise_and( frame, frame)
            #cv2.add(bg, frame)
            origVidImgHeight, origVidImgWidth = frame.shape[:2]
            print(frame.shape)
            #orig_mask = frame[:,:,2]
            #orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)


            xVidPosition = int((screenW / 3)*2)
            yVidPosition = int((screenH / 4)*3)

            x1 = int(xVidPosition - (origVidImgWidth / 2))
            x2 = int(xVidPosition + (origVidImgWidth / 2))
            y1 = int(yVidPosition - (origVidImgHeight / 2))
            y2 = int(yVidPosition + (origVidImgHeight / 2))

            roi = bg[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            #roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and( roi, roi, mask = orig_mask_inv)
            #roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and( frame, frame, mask = orig_mask)

            #dst = cv2.add(roi_bg, roi_fg)

            bg[y1:y2, x1:x2] = frame
            SetDisplayImg(bg, "")
         else:
            break
      vid.release()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Can you do some work to narrow this down? Start removing/simplifying some of the code until you have the least amount needed to reproduce the issue? Also, what is `bg`? It's the return value of `GetDisplayImgContent()`, but that's not provided.

Comment: # Get the image content to display
def GetDisplayImgContent():
   global displayImgContent
   return displayImgContent

Comment: # Set the image to display with the file name
def SetDisplayImg(img, imgName):
   global displayImgContent
   global displayImgName
   displayImgName = imgName
   displayImgContent=img